# Converting Savitzky-Golay filter in python to R

Tags: python, r, signals, data-preprocessing, spectra

I want to preprocess spectra using a Savitzky-Golay filter in R.  Do to this I need the equivalent of this Python code (using scipy.signal):

```
savgol_filter(X, 11, 2, 1, mode = 'nearest')
```

Using the package 'signal' I can use this, but this does not replicate the above at all.

```
sgolayfilt(X, n = 11, p = 2, m = 1)
```

Thanks!